# Create Folder Hierachy

Tags: python, directory-structure

I am currently learning the basics of Python. At the moment, I am trying to write a script which creates folders (1st hierarchy) from a text file list, each with the the same subfolder structure which goes down to 3 hierarchies.

I've managed to do the first part: Create the 1st hierarchy folders from a text file.

```
from sys import argv

import os;
home_dir = '/home/tobi/Python'

mylist = open('test.txt','r')
for folder in mylist:
folder = folder.strip()
 newFolder = home_dir+'/'+folder
 print "Folder name " +newFolder
 if not os.path.exists(newFolder):
           os.makedirs(newFolder)
   os.chdir(newFolder)
mylist.close()
```

Now I am struggling to create a loop to insert my given subfolder structure in each of the created folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you have the directories listed in test.txt?

Comment: Each Line is a folder name:
01_Stream1
02_Stream2
...

Each top-folder will have the same subfolders: 01_Subfolder1, 02_Subfolder2 and s on. I have no list for the subfolders as there are only 8.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You are managing to create directories, and changing into said directories. Why can't you create even more directories? Also, `the same subfolder structure which goes down to 3 hierarchies` contradicts `Each top-folder will have the same subfolders: 01_Subfolder1, 02_Subfolder2 and s on. I have no list for the subfolders as there are only 8`. You need to provide a concrete problem, plus any other information somebody would need to solve *your* problem. Please, have a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should take a break to clear your mind and then rewrite your question, e.g. your question is

> Create Folder Hierachy from Text files

but then you write

> I've managed to do the first part: Create the 1st hierarchy folders from a text file.

You also contradict yourself about the structure of the subdirectories ... but here's a guess for the flat hierarchy to get you started on your "loop problem".
Note that I'm using Python 3, so you might have to adapt a thing or two. Also, I'm not actually creating directories (so this might fail for you and you might have to join paths):

```
import os

home_dir = "."#'/home/tobi/Python'

# don't have your subdirectory structure, making something up ...
subdirs = [ "{0:02}_Subfolder{0}".format(n) for n in range(1,8+1)]

#with open('test.txt','r') as mylist: # don't have your file, making something up ...
mylist = ["one", "two", "three"]
# indent for with
for folder in mylist:
    folder = folder.strip()
    newFolder = home_dir + '/' + folder
    print("Folder name " + newFolder)
    if not os.path.exists(newFolder):
        #os.makedirs(newFolder)
        print("mkdir:", newFolder) # just pretending

    #os.chdir(newFolder)
    print("cwd:", newFolder) # just pretending

    # just another loop like the one you already came up with (did you really?)
    for subdir in subdirs:
        if not os.path.exists(subdir):
            #os.makedirs(subdir)
            print("mkdir:", subdir) # just pretending

# done
```

gives

```
Folder name ./one
mkdir: ./one
cwd: ./one
mkdir: 01_Subfolder1
mkdir: 02_Subfolder2
mkdir: 03_Subfolder3
mkdir: 04_Subfolder4
mkdir: 05_Subfolder5
mkdir: 06_Subfolder6
mkdir: 07_Subfolder7
mkdir: 08_Subfolder8
Folder name ./two
mkdir: ./two
cwd: ./two
mkdir: 01_Subfolder1
mkdir: 02_Subfolder2
mkdir: 03_Subfolder3
mkdir: 04_Subfolder4
mkdir: 05_Subfolder5
mkdir: 06_Subfolder6
mkdir: 07_Subfolder7
mkdir: 08_Subfolder8
Folder name ./three
mkdir: ./three
cwd: ./three
mkdir: 01_Subfolder1
mkdir: 02_Subfolder2
mkdir: 03_Subfolder3
mkdir: 04_Subfolder4
mkdir: 05_Subfolder5
mkdir: 06_Subfolder6
mkdir: 07_Subfolder7
mkdir: 08_Subfolder8
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply! Problem solved! To all repliers: Sorry for my imprecise problem description. I guess the correct formulation would have been: Insert a subfolder structure to every folder in a given directory. I also guess it is more a lack of basic knowledge on my side than a problem. I will get more into the basics before posting my next question!